# Duvida sobre conversão de str para int com py/pandas ((dataset))

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Eu tenho uma coluna de notas no formato de string. Elas vem tipo: 432432.0
Sempre vem com .0 aí eu queria passar logo pra int e nao pra float
Como ta nesse formato vi que eu deveria primeiro converter pra float e depois pra int
Só que tem algumas linhas que tinham a string "Unknown" que eu previamente mudei tudo pra None
Aí quando eu rodo a conversao de float pra int da esse erro:

```
ValueError: Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer
```

eu consigo resolver esse erro com essa modificação aqui:

disso:

```
data['Score-9'] = data['Score-9'].astype(int)
```

pra isso:

```
data['Score-9'] = data['Score-9'].fillna(0).astype(int)
```

mas não quero que as lacunas do None fiquem com 0 pois isso vai alterar as médias, medianas e afins. Como posso fazer a conversão continuando com o None e sem dar erro?

Comment: Acredito que acrescentas a média nos `nan` irá afetar mediana e moda. A pergunta deve ser o que fazer com os "Unknown". Se eles devem ser ignorados, substitua eles por `np.nan`, para isso importe o numpy (`import numpy as np`). Com isso: uma série `1, nan, 3` teria média = 2.

Answer (score 1):

Em cálculo de média, mediana e moda; o valor `NaN` é ignorado.

Dê preferênci para o tipo `float`.

Veja o exemplo:

### Criando DataFrame teste

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"valores": ["1", "1", "Unknown", "4"]})

df
   valores
0        1
1        1
2  Unknown
3        4
```

### Convertendo `Unkown` para `NaN`

```
import numpy as np

df = df.replace("Unknown", np.nan)
```

### Caso vc tente converter para `int`, será lançada a exceção

```
df["valores"] = df["valores"].astype(int)
(...)
ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer
```

### Convertendo para float

```
df["valores"] = df["valores"].astype(float)

df
   valores
0      1.0
1      1.0
2      NaN
3      4.0
```

### Média, mediana, moda

```
df["valores"].mean()
2.0

df["valores"].median()
1.0

df["valores"].mode()
0    1.0
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar o lambda desta forma para remover o ".0" já que seus números são inteiros

`data['Score-9'] = data['Score-9'].apply(lambda x: x.replace('.0', ''))`

Answer (score -1):

O que você pode fazer é tratar os valores "Unknown" para 0 assim quando converter para int não terá esse erro.

Caso você não queira os valores como 0, após a conversão, altere os 0 para None

Comment: A pergunta descreve que ele não quer usar 0 (zero) para não alterar a média etc...

Comment: Não cumprimente e não agradeça nas publicações. Veja https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/behavior